# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac {a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+\cdots+a_nb_0}{n+1}=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}a_k \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}b_m$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits

> Let $a_n , b_n$ be convergent sequences of complex numbers. Show that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac {a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+\cdots+a_nb_0}{n+1}=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}a_k \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}b_m$$

Unless I am missing something here, this is equivalent to stating that if $a_n \rightarrow a, b_n \rightarrow b$, $a,b \in \Bbb{C}$, then show that: 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac {a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+\cdots+a_nb_0}{n+1}=ab$$
Though I have not been able to show this, I know of a similar statement, that is:
If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n=a,  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_n=b$, then:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac {a_0b_0+a_1b_1+\cdots+a_nb_n}{n+1}=ab$$
We go about doing this by setting $c_n=a_nb_n-ab$ and noticing that $|c_n|<M$ for $M \in \Bbb{R}$ since $c_n\rightarrow 0$. 

Also since $c_n$ converges, let $\epsilon>0$ and $m \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $$|c_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{2} \forall n\ge m$$

 and $n_1\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $$\frac{1}{n}<\frac{\epsilon}{2mM} \forall n \ge n_1$$

For $N=m+n_1$ and taking into account the above, we have

$$\Big|\frac{a_0b_0+a_1b_1+\cdots+a_nb_n}{n+1}-ab\Big|=\\\Big|\frac{c_0+c_1+\cdots+c_n}{n+1}\Big|=\\\Big|\frac{(c_0+c_1+\cdots+c_m)+(c_{m+1}+c_{m+2}+\cdots+c_n)}{n+1} \Big|\le \\\frac{|c_0|+|c_1|+\cdots+|c_m|}{n+1}+\frac{|c_{m+1}|+|c_{m+2}|+\cdots+|c_n|}{n+1}\\ \le \frac{mM}{N}+\frac{n-m}{n}\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$$ 

It follows that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac {a_0b_0+a_1b_1+\cdots+a_nb_n}{n+1}=ab$$

Is there any way to manipulate the above in order to get the desired equality or we need a different approach altogether? And another point that I can't seem to understand is where are we going to use the fact that $a_n,b_n$ are sequences of complex numbers? I believe the above is correct in both $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{C}$. In any case, I think that we need some algebraic manipulation to help us, but I can't come up with it so far.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725914/find-the-limit-lim-n-to-infty-fracx-1-y-n-x-2-y-n-1-cdots-x-n-y-1

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real numbers are also complex numbers, therefore the assertion also holds if you only consider a real sequence.

The approach can indeed be modified to fit this theorem. Since $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent, they are bounded by a constant $C$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary and Choose $N$ sufficiently large, so that $|a_n - a|, |b_n - b| \le \frac{\epsilon}{C}$ for all $n \ge N$.

Now use a similar approach and the inequality $|a_i b_j - ab| \le C\min(|a_i - a|, |b_j - b|)$. Note that at least one of $i$ or $j$ will be large if $n$ is large, since $i + j = n$.

Comment: This seems to do the trick! I will work out the details. Thanks a lot Dominik!