# $(\sum_{k\in[\sqrt{n},n-\sqrt{n}]}1)$ vanishes in $\frac{1}{n}(\sum_{k\in[\sqrt{n},n-\sqrt{n}]}1)(M+|\alpha|)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> The following derivation took place in another thread.
>
> $\Bigl|\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k\in[\sqrt{n},n-\sqrt{n}]}a_kb_{n-k}-\alpha\beta\,\Bigr|\le\frac{1}{n}\,\Bigl(\sum\limits_{k\in[\sqrt{n},n-\sqrt{n}]}1\Bigr)(M+|\alpha|)\,\epsilon\le(M+|\alpha|)\,\epsilon$

However I am having a hard time understanding how $\sum\limits_{k\in[\sqrt{n},n-\sqrt{n}]}1$ vanishes. I thought that $n-\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n}=n-2\sqrt{n}=1$, but I have no idea if this is the way and if this last equality is true.

**Question:**

Could someone explain me how $\sum\limits_{k\in[\sqrt{n},n-\sqrt{n}]}1$ vanishes?

Thanks in advance!

To prevent potential doubts here is the link to the other thread [$\frac{a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+...+a_nb_0}{n}$ converges to $\alpha\beta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2901175/fraca-0b-na-1b-n-1-a-nb-0n-converges-to-alpha-beta)

Comment: is $\sum_{k\in A} f(k)$ supposed to be an integral here? That should be clarified. It's an exotic notation.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin It is the summation over all integers $k$ in the set $A$. Even though $A$ may be uncountable, you only sum over the integers in it.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Please check my update! Thanks!

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin               Please check my update! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac1n\big(\sum_{k\in [\sqrt{n},n-\sqrt{n}]}1\big)\le \frac1n\big(\sum_{k=1}^n1\big)=\frac1n\cdot n=1,$$
so
$$
\frac1n\big(\sum_{k\in [\sqrt{n},n-\sqrt{n}]}1\big)(M+|\alpha|)\epsilon \le (M+|\alpha|)\epsilon
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Why did you use $[\sqrt{n}]$?

Comment: @PedroGomes I have edited with a simpler proof.