# If $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$ then $\frac1n(a_1b_n+a_2b_{n-1}+\cdots+a_nb_1)\to ab$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

#### Problem

Given $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n=a$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}b_n=b$, prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_1b_n+a_2b_{n-1}+\cdots+a_nb_1}{n}=ab.$$

#### My Proof

Denote $x_n=a_n-a,~~~y_n=b_n-b.$ Then $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}y_n=0,\tag1$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k}{n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n y_k}{n}=0,\tag2$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k^2}{n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n y_k^2}{n}=0.\tag3$$
Moreover, since

$$0\leq\left|\vcenter{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_ky_{n-k+1}}{n}}\right|\leq\vcenter{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n |x_ky_{n-k+1}|}{n}}\leq\vcenter{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (x_k^2+y_{k}^2)}{2n}}\to 0~~~(n \to \infty),$$
then $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_ky_{n-k+1}}{n}=0.\tag4$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_kb_{n-k+1}}{n}&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n [(x_k+a)(y_{n-k+1}+b)]}{n}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_ky_{n-k+1}+b\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k+a\sum\limits_{k=1}^n y_{n-k+1}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n ab}{n}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_ky_{n-k+1}}{n}+b\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k}{n}+a\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n y_{n-k+1}}{n}+\lim_{n \to \infty}ab\\
&=0+b\cdot 0+a\cdot 0+ab\\
&=ab.
\end{align*}

Comment: Seems about right

Comment: @user10354138 but that's not right. We have $\sum a_kb_{n-k}$

Comment: I vertically centered the fractions in the line with the absolute values. If this is not okay, simply revert my edit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_1 y_n + x_2 y_{n-1} + \cdots + x_n y_1}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725914/find-the-limit-lim-n-to-infty-fracx-1-y-n-x-2-y-n-1-cdots-x-n-y-1)