# Finding the limit of a sequence having epsilon

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

If $a_n$ → a, $b_n$ → b, then $c_n$ = ($a_1$$b_n$+$a_2$$b_{n−1}$+···+$a_n$$b_1$)\n → ab.

Hint: Write
$a_n$ = a + $\epsilon$$_n$, where $\epsilon$ → 0. Then:

$c_n$ = ($a_1$$b_n$+$a_2$$b_{n−1}$+···+$a_n$$b_1$)\n = a
[($b_n$ + $b_{n−1}$ + ··· + $b_1$)/n]+[($\epsilon_1$$b_n$ + $\epsilon_2$$b_{n-1}$ + ··· + $\epsilon_n$$b_1$)/n]

The Questions:

The first part tends to ab (why?), and it remains to show that the second part
tends to zero

Comment: My answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/727180/72031 uses the hint given in your question.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yes, thank you